# Allowing umlauts in Sitecore WFFM Regular expression validator

Tags: wffm

We need to allow the German umlauts for the user to enter as part of user name.  While we add

```
^[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß-.]+(?:[._-][A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß-.]+)*$
```

This is not working as expected and we just get an error as "Facing Technical difficulty"

Comment: Have you tried to encode umlets? So use `^[A-Za-z0-9&#228;&#246;&#252;&#196;&#214;&#220;&#223;-.]+`...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your regular expression is not correct. "-" sign in regular expressions is used to match any from range of characters. e.g.: `A-Z` or `a-z`. You have range that is not closed: `ß-`  I removed "-" sign and [it started to work for me](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C%C3%9F.%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5B._-%5D%5BA-Za-z0-9%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C%C3%9F.%5D%2B%29*%24&i=%C3%84%C3%96asrfga%C3%84).

```
^[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß.]+(?:[._-][A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß.]+)*$
```

Update following comment of @Marek Musielak. It seems that under `-.` @PVM have meant either `.` or `-` characters. In regular expression these [characters should be escaped](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C%C3%9F%5C-%5C.%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5B._-%5D%5BA-Za-z0-9%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C%C3%9F%5C-%5C.%5D%2B%29*%24&i=%C3%84%C3%96asrfga%C3%84-.):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß\-\.]+(?:[._-][A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß\-\.]+)*$
```

Comment: So there should be `\\`` character before `-`, right? `-` should not be removed?

Comment: Yes, if @PVM wants to use '-' character then it should be escaped "\-". I was not sure, why this symbol was added, but it definitely causes issue

Answer (score -2):

```
/^[ A-Za-z\-_.\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF.~\\-]*$/
```

Please try to use this one.

Answer (score -5):

Try this one.

```
^[ A-Za-z\u00C0-\u017F.~\\-]*$
```

Comment: Can you add some more details about what you fixed and how it works?